# Manipulating data in a different format

Tags: javascript, node.js

I managed to create a query to get some data from the database using the following script:

```
app.get("/diseases", async (req, res) => {
  const rows = await process.postgresql.query(
    "SELECT ds.disease, ds.symptom FROM diseases ds"
  );
  console.log(rows);
  res.status(200).send(JSON.stringify(rows));
});
```

The data comes in the following format:

```
[
  { disease: ' boală hipertensivă', symptom: ' durere toracică' },
  {
    disease: ' boală hipertensivă',
    symptom: ' respirație întretăiată'
  },
  { disease: ' boală hipertensivă', symptom: ' amețeală' },
  { disease: ' boală hipertensivă', symptom: ' astenie' },
  { disease: ' boală hipertensivă', symptom: ' toamnă (Fall)' },
  { disease: ' boală hipertensivă', symptom: ' sincopă' },
  { disease: ' diabet', symptom: ' poliurie' }
]
```

My question is how to transform this data in a format, like the following:

```
{"Hypertensive disease": ["Pain chest", "Shortness of breath", "Dizziness", "Asthenia", "Fall", "Syncope", "Vertigo", "Sweat", "Sweating increased", "Palpitation", "Nausea", "Angina pectoris", "Pressure chest"], "Diabetes": ["Polyuria"]}
```

Comment: How are both the data related? Are you using any kind of ... Okay I guess I got what you want.

Comment: reduce ! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40774697/how-can-i-group-an-array-of-objects-by-key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to group and transpose the data. The best way is to use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function on the array. Here's an example:

```js
const arr = [
  { disease: "boală hipertensivă", symptom: " durere toracică" },
  { disease: "boală hipertensivă", symptom: " respirație întretăiată" },
  { disease: "boală hipertensivă", symptom: " amețeală" },
  { disease: "boală hipertensivă", symptom: " astenie" },
  { disease: "boală hipertensivă", symptom: " toamnă (Fall)" },
  { disease: "boală hipertensivă", symptom: " sincopă" },
  { disease: "diabet", symptom: " poliurie" }
];
console.log(arr.reduce((group, row) => {
  // Check if disease group has the disease
  if (typeof group[row.disease] === "undefined") {
    // Initialise an array.
    group[row.disease] = [];
  }
  // Push the symptoms.
  group[row.disease].push(row.symptom.trim());
  // return the updated group.
  return group;
}, {}));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

For the given input above, I get this response:

```
{
  "boală hipertensivă": [
    "durere toracică",
    "respirație întretăiată",
    "amețeală",
    "astenie",
    "toamnă (Fall)",
    "sincopă"
  ],
  "diabet": [
    "poliurie"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return rows.reduce((acc, item) => { if (!!acc[item.disease]) acc[item.disease].push(item.symptom); else acc[item.disease] = [item.symptom]; return acc; }, {})
```

The `reduce` function takes two parameters - an iteration processing function, which accumulates a result, and initial result (we put as initial result an empty object `{}` ).

The iteration processor has two params - the accumulator object `acc` and current item `item`, and it should return new (or modified) accumulator object.

On each iteration our function checks if `acc` already has a field with 'disease' value. If it doesnt' - it creates this field and puts 1 item array `[item.symptom]` inside. If the field already exists, it pushes a symptom to that array. After we process data we get the object with deseases as keys, and arrays of their symptoms as values.

Comment: It would be really helpful for the user to explain what's happening rather than putting up a minified code, don't you think? 